# One-liner editor with Codemirror 5

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to replace `input type="text"` with a CodeMirror instance and avoid creating extra lines. I would like to use the beforeChange event and call the cancel() method if a line break is detected. However, the change object does not seem to provide any information about line changes.

Something like:

```
cm.on('beforeChange', function(e, change){
    //  if change.text[] contains \r\n call change.cancel();
});
```

Unfortunately `change.text` contains empty array on "enter".

This has to be done with Codemirror 5 (not v6).

Comment: https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/single-line-codemirror/195  -- looks like a solution